# Adding a specific range of numbers to an array

Tags: java, arrays

I have been looking and looking at my code and I still can't figure out why the result is always the highestGrade value and not a different value for every position in the array.

Here is my code:

```
int[] gradesDescription;
int[] gradesCount;

gradesDescription = new int[(highestGrade-lowestGrade) + 1];
gradesCount = new int[(highestGrade-lowestGrade) + 1];

for(int b = lowestGrade; b <= highestGrade; b++){
  Arrays.fill(gradesDescription, b);
}

for(int d = 0; d < gradesDescription.length; d++){
 System.out.println("Grade: " + gradesDescription[d] + 
                    " had " + gradesCount[d] + " students with the same grade.");
```

What is the logic that I am missing; is there a better way on how to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is causing your problem:

```
Arrays.fill(gradesDescription, b);
```

This will assign EVERY value in `gradesDescription` to `b`.  What you want instead is something like:

```
for(int b = 0; b < gradesDescription.length; b++) {
    gradesDescription[b] = b + lowestGrade;
}
```

Although, I have to say even this code looks wrong.  What is the expected behavior if there are three students with grades of 70, 80, and 100?  `gradesDescription.length` will end up being 30, but really it should only be 3?  I'm assuming you left out the code where the elements of `gradesCount` are assigned?

Comment: Great Description! I got the logic now and I also saw that Arrays.fill was just sending the same value to my array. Thanks!

Comment: I am using a different array to go through a file that holds certain grades and I need to count how many students received the same grade for every grade (range between lowestGrade to highestGrade) and then I will assign each count to the correspondent position that matches gradesDescription. Then I will just print the grade and the amount of students with the same grade.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int b = lowestGrade; b <= highestGrade; b++){
     Arrays.fill(gradesDescription, b);
}
```

This line will place the value in `b` at every position in your `gradesDescription` array. Hence the same value every time.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays.fill is filling the entire array with the same value each time through the loop.  I think you wanted

```
for(int idx = 0; idx < gradesDescription.length; idx++){
  gradesDescription[idx] = idx + lowestGrade;
}
```